# Is anyone else getting "Service temporarily unavailable." from Google Books API?

Tags: google-api

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendFailed",
    "message": "Service temporarily unavailable.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "backend_flow"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Service temporarily unavailable."
 }
}
```

Started to get this error several hours ago in response to Google Books API: `Volume: list`

For example, copy-paste the following line into the URL box of your internet browser:

> https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=orwell

Comment: which API end-point are you hitting?

Comment: Volume: List (see https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes/list)

Comment: I wonder if Google is aware of it and already working on a fix... Google system status indicate that all services are OK...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be useful to refer to the definition of a 503 response code for insight into what to expect.

#### 503 Service Unavailable

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

**Note:** In my experiment the endpoint mentioned did not provide any `Retry-After` header.

#### What to do...

"If I'm not back in 5 minutes, just wait longer." — [Ace Ventura](https://memes.yarn.co/yarn-clip/879507d3-0112-45c8-abcc-e0d0c5be64af/text), Pet Detective.